# MsSql Server , update query execution took too much time

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have a sql server db keeping our text document datas.

A specific table is keeping thousands of text paragraphs themself, This table suddenly started to respond so lately to update queries abnormally. Sometimes non-complicated basic update query takes 30 - 40 secs. to execute and asp.net application uses this table throws timeout exception.

Select queries last normal as before but update.

Why this happens and what should I do?

Server system is **Windows 2008 R2 Standard** and **MsSql Server 2008 R2**

Below's my table meta data.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MetinIcerikTablosuCari](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MetinIsimID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MetinIsimID_Eski_1] [int] NULL,
    [MetinIsimID_Eski_2] [int] NULL,
    [MetinIsimID_Eski_3] [int] NULL,
    [MetinIsimID_Eski_4] [int] NULL,
    [MetinIsimID_Eski_5] [int] NULL,
    [MetinIcindekilerID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SilmeTalebi] [bit] NULL,
    [SiraNo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ParagrafMetin] [text] NOT NULL,
    [RevizeParagraf] [text] NULL,
    [RevizeVarMi] [bit] NULL,
    [RevizasyonOnayi] [bit] NULL,
    [RevizasyonTarihi] [datetime] NULL,
    [RevizasyonSahibiID] [int] NULL,
    [RevizasyonOnayTarihi] [datetime] NULL,
    [RevizasyonOnaylayanID] [int] NULL,
    [RevizasyonSonOnay] [bit] NULL,
    [RevizeTuru] [int] NULL,
    [ParagrafRevizeIslemJetonu] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [BaglantiliOrtakRevizeSeriNo] [int] NULL,
    [SonOnayTarihi] [datetime] NULL,
    [SonOnaylayanID] [int] NULL,
    [ParagrafMetin_Eski_1] [text] NULL,
    [ParagrafMetin_Eski_2] [text] NULL,
    [ParagrafMetin_Eski_3] [text] NULL,
    [ParagrafMetin_Eski_4] [text] NULL,
    [ParagrafMetin_Eski_5] [text] NULL,
    [GirisTarihi] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [YayinTarihi] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ParagrafNot] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [DipNotTag] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [MedyaURL] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [MedyaUrlNot] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [VersiyonMetin] [int] NULL,
    [EtkileyenMetinID] [int] NULL,
    [tarih] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [GuncellemeTarihi] [datetime] NULL,
    [NotParagrafi] [bit] NULL,
    [YeniParagraf] [bit] NULL,
    [MedyaParagrafi] [bit] NULL,
    [EslestirmeSilmeOnayID] [int] NULL,
    [YargiOnBilgiSayfasi] [bit] NULL,
    [BolumParagrafi] [bit] NULL,
    [UstParagrafID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MetinIcerikTablosuCari] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MetinIcerikTablosuCari] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MetinIcerikTablosuCari_MetinIsimID]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [MetinIsimID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MetinIcerikTablosuCari] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MetinIcerikTablosuCari_MetinIcindekilerID]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [MetinIcindekilerID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MetinIcerikTablosuCari] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MetinIcerikTablosuCari_SiraNo]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [SiraNo]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MetinIcerikTablosuCari] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MetinIcerikTablosuCari_ParagrafMetin]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [ParagrafMetin]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MetinIcerikTablosuCari] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MetinIcerikTablosuCari_RevizeTuru]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [RevizeTuru]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MetinIcerikTablosuCari] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MetinIcerikTablosuCari_ParagrafNot]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [ParagrafNot]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MetinIcerikTablosuCari] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MetinIcerikTablosuCari_DipNotTag]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [DipNotTag]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MetinIcerikTablosuCari] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MetinIcerikTablosuCari_MedyaUrlNot]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [MedyaUrlNot]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MetinIcerikTablosuCari] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MetinIcerikTablosuCari_NotParagrafi]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [NotParagrafi]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MetinIcerikTablosuCari] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MetinIcerikTablosuCari_YeniParagraf]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [YeniParagraf]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MetinIcerikTablosuCari] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MetinIcerikTablosuCari_MedyaParagrafi]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [MedyaParagrafi]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MetinIcerikTablosuCari] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MetinIcerikTablosuCari_EslestirmeSilmeOnayID]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [EslestirmeSilmeOnayID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MetinIcerikTablosuCari] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MetinIcerikTablosuCari_YargiOnBilgiSayfasi]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [YargiOnBilgiSayfasi]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MetinIcerikTablosuCari] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MetinIcerikTablosuCari_BolumParagrafi]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [BolumParagrafi]
GO
```

I checked out and executed the update stats sp, but it seems the problem keeps going.

A simple update query like this: `update MetinIcerikTablosuCari set ParagrafMetin = '<p>SPK Bültenleri - 2002/34: #media#93640#media#</p>' where ID = 35606` takes 20 - 30 secs or more.

I checked the CPU usage while the query executing, it suddenly picks to appr. 75 - 80%.

I could not determine if it's about lack of server memory or sql uses memory abnormally.

Below is my server hardware specifications:

**Windows 2008 R2 Standard - Service Pack1**
**Processor**: Intel Core i5-2400 CPU @ 3.1 Ghz
**RAM**: 8GB
**System Type**: 64-bit

In addition, could this be kind of lack of updates for Windows Server or MsSql Server 2008 r2

Comment: Others will be able to help you better if you post the SQL statement that triggers the problem, as well as the table definition. Also, it is not clear whether you are referring to MySQL or SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

As you haven't provided the execution plan and other necessary details, my assumption is that you might have indexes which are causing slow updates. Indexes helps running SELECT fast but slow down insert and update statements. List out all the indexes (Clustered & Non-Clustered) and then remove unnecessary indexes from your table. 
Also, how often do you update statistics? If that is not recently done then run following SP

> EXEC Sp_Updatestats;

If above two ways doesn't solve your problem then I recommend you to post table metadata and execution plan.

Comment: Thank you so much, I cheched the indexes, there is no other Index but Table primary key (clustered). Now I executed the sp you sent, It resulted as tens of index updates and it seemed it got Update queries faster.

Comment: If the problem keeps on I will post detailed Info about table definition. Thank you.

Comment: @ErdemSekerci I am glad it helped. Updating stats should be a regular maintenance activity. Also verify that AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS and AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS are on

Comment: How can i check if they are on? And if so do this mean, stats updates will be made automatically in periods not to need make manual?

Comment: @ErdemSekerci Here is a quick query tutorial for that http://sqlserverdb.blogspot.in/2011/08/how-to-check-autocreatestatistics-is.html

Comment: thank you so much. I solved my problem by the way. I have removed the clustered index comes from ID primary key and setting operations turned to be normal. But it's a big question why the ID index caused this.